# Sharepoint SiteUserInfoList get all keys and values

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I need to get all key and value pairs from Sharepoint 2013 `SiteUserInfoList` list.

I currently have following code:

```
            SPWeb web = new SPSite("http://sp2013:2013/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx").OpenWeb();
            SPList item = web.SiteUserInfoList;

            foreach (SPListItem f in item.Items)
            {
                foreach (var it in f.Fields)
                {
                    // Here I would like to print out key value pairs
                    Console.WriteLine("Tile: {0}:{1}", it, it.ToString());
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: How about saying what knowledge you are currently missing to complete this task? If the list of items is not to big, it should easily work (although you would have to use `f[it]` where you are currently using `it.ToString()`, and maybe `it.Title` where you are using `it`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Tile: {0}:{1}", it.Title, f[it.Title]);
```

[SPFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield_properties.aspx) is a key value collection. To access its value, you need to pass the corresponding key.